# Apache on windows and php-fpm

Tags: php, windows, apache

php 7.1

Apache 2.4 + mod_proxy_fcgi

Windows 10

I'm trying to set up php-fpm + apache on windows, using mod_proxy_fcgi but keep getting errors. Can anyone help me with configuring apache.

I got php-fpm runnig, and verified that it actually works using nginx, so php should not be a problem.

PHP-fpm is running on port 9123.

Here is my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9123
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the error:

> Proxy Error
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. The
>   proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.php/.
>
> Reason: URI cannot be parsed:
>   fcgi://127.0.0.1:9123C:/Apache24/htdocs/index.php*

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: I've the same problem. Could you please share your solution?

Comment: My solution was switching to linux or use nginx instead

Comment: Clearly that's the single "best" approach, but sometime is unfaseable due to business requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dealing with the same issue and I found the root cause: most likely we were both following the [this wiki.apache.org guide](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM). There are a couple of typos in said guide. What causes the problem for us is that there is a missing slash after `SetHandler`. This is the config that worked for me:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9123/"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting the:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9123
</FilesMatch>
```

outside the directory? Ie. what happens if you put that part between the docroot directive and the directory directive?

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like :

```
<FilesMatch "^/CHANGE_ME/.*\.php(/.*)?$">
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9123
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work either. But no error is displayed at all. I just can see content of my index.php on the screen that's it. May-be Im doing something wrong. what exactly is supposed to be in place of "CHANGE_ME" ?

Comment: Hi. It should be your project folder